# Bot is not responding to the input given (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I watched a tutorial on how to get Input from users in Discord.py. The bot however, does not respond to the input given to it.

The bot sends the "This is a bot test. Type (YES/NO)" message. But when I type "yes" or "no" it does not respond.

```
@client.command()
async def bot(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("This is a bot test. Type (YES/NO)")

    try:
        message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel, timeout=30.0)
  
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.channel.send("I have been ignored")

    else:
        if message.content.lower() == "yes":
            await ctx.channel.send("The test was succesfull!")
    
        elif message.content.lower() == "no":
            await ctx.channel.send("Thank you for your response")
    
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send("I cannot understand you")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're decorating with `client` but calling `bot` in your function.

Change

```py
@client.command()
async def bot(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("This is a bot test. Type (YES/NO)")

    try:
        message = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel, timeout=30.0)
```

To

```py
@client.command()
async def bot(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("This is a bot test. Type (YES/NO)")

    try:
        message = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel, timeout=30.0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works

Comment: Very welcome. Please accept my answer if my solution is working to your satisfaction